# How to remove a class from the classpath after Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a jar that I need to include in my dependencies...

```
compile files('WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/wls-api.jar')
```

There's a class inside that jar that is causing trouble that I want to not be on the classpath when I run my app after a gradle build.

How do I get rid of that class after doing a gradle build?

Comment: How do you run the app after build? As a jar, war?

Comment: I run the app as a jar

Comment: I don't know if it's a "fat" jar or not...I just do `gradle build` and then run the jar (`java -jar myApp.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit trickier than it looks like at first blink; because you will modify the original input!
You should create a configuration for the your modified artifact (this is a proof of concept build.gradle snipplet):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task filteredJar(type:Jar){
    // you may use a remote artifact by configuring a separate configuration for it and using a jar from:
    // configurations.theConfig.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts
    from zipTree('a.jar')
    archiveName 'xx.jar'
    // use standard Copy/Sync like filters here, for the example i used
    include '**/Tool.class'
}

configurations {
    z1
}
artifacts {
    z1  filteredJar
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: getPath(), configuration: 'z1')
}
```

or..alternatively, and might be more preferably:
put this magic into some separate project which will repackage this jar into a usebale one.